# What are the hidden cost while deploying game with Unity3D?

Tags: android, unity, xbox360, licensing, ipad

I just started learning Unity3D. I created a small 2D game, and I want to host for Windows, iPhone, iPad, Android, Windows 8, Xbox and even on websites.

I created it using **free Unity3D editor.** Now I want to host all these game on my website.

I will purchase iPhone, Android, and Windows 8 developer accounts. Apart from that, do I need to purchase any license in order to deploy the game on my website?

I can lots of license here: https://store.unity3d.com/

If I later purchase Unity Pro, then do I need to purchase any extra licenses?

And will that Unity logo always appear while starting the game?

Comment: The store clearly shows you the option to add those licenses the moment you select Unity Pro. You can pick between the Pro version or normal versions between those as well.

Comment: That means if I take android pro, I need to take ios license worth $400 extra. Can someone quickly shed light on everything thing here.

Comment: It's really not that hard. If you want those features you have to buy those as well. You also need an xcode compiler ( you probably need a mac for that in case you dont have it ) for iOS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to have a look at this [page](http://unity3d.com/unity/licenses), that shows license features comparison.

You can deploy to `iOS`,`Android` or `Flash` buying the related licenses without buying `Unity3D` pro license. 
The pro license has more features than the normal one. Buying it it's more a matter of features than target platforms.

> I created it using free unity3d editor. Now I want to host all these
>   game on my website.
>
> I will purchase iphone, android and windows 8 developer account. Apart
>   from that, do I need to purchase any license in order to deploy game
>   on my website.

You need `iOS` and Android license to target those platforms. AFAIK you can use a `Unity` plugin to play game in your browser without a specific license (for the `Flash` one you have to pay)

> If I will purchase unity pro then do I need to purchase any extra
>   license?

For anything else than pc platform or web using `Unity` plugin yes, you need to purchase the platform specific license.

> And will that unity logo will always appear while starting game.

To remove it you need `Unity` pro license.

Comment: Is there a similar tool, which have code in xna and allow user to quickly design game and features like level editing, creating user profile, settings, highest score, etc stuff.

Comment: That's a separate question (and arguably off-topic for this site).

Answer (score 0):

You will need Unity's iOS and Android licenses as well if you plan on releasing on those platforms.

Comment: What If I will purchase unity pro then do I need to purchase any extra license?

And will that unity logo will always appear while starting game.

Comment: Also, I think the XBox 360 license requires that you have the XBox 360 SDK (this is not XNA), which costs a lot, and unless you are a company, you will probably not be able to get your hands on it.

Comment: Is there a similar tool, which integrates with xna and allow user to quickly design game and features like level editing, creating user profile, settings, highest score, etc stuff. Doing all this with xna will make developer crazy.

Comment: XNA is actually rather easy. But there are existing engines as well - just google for it. From the top of my head I can think of the FlatReadBall engine and the Sunburn engine. But those won't deploy to iOS and Android.

Comment: for Sunburn engine you need to pay 1000$ to purchase their editior

Comment: Do you really need the Studio edition? There are far cheaper licenses available. The Professional edition says it has all Features and is only 300$. There's also the Indie License for half the price which might even be enough, depending on your game.

Answer (score 0):

If you were already immersed in XNA then an option would be to port it using [MonoGame](https://www.monogame.net) which is a replacement for the now expiring XNA. Going that route you could likely still use dev kits such as FlatRedBall and then you would just have to tweak the code for the various implementations (iOS and Android) plus pay the cost for the dev accounts for each of those platforms. That is usually less than $100, but for iOS you will still need a Mac in the end regardless... must pay the apple tax.

MonoGame itself is free however it is still under fairly intense development so it is not for the faint of heart.

Answer (score 0):

Unity's store page should be straight forward.  If you want to deploy on iOS you need an iOS license.  If you need/want features from Unity Pro, you need the Unity Pro license (or if you don't qualify for their indie license).

The only other costs associated with deploying to the various platforms are the developer licenses from Apple/Google to actually deploy your app on their app stores.